# Browserlink error on Chrome with VS2017 .NET Core App

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, web-essentials, browser-link

Web Essentials 2017 is already installed as part of Visual Studio 2017, but when I run an ASP.NET Core app in the Chrome Dev Tools console window I get the following error message

> "Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback: TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'files' of null"

On the same console window, I also see the following error message related to Browserlink:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

[image: Browserlink issue]

Second question, I've noticed with Chrome, making CSS changes in my solution and just refreshing the page doesn't change the CSS on the browser -  I have to close out of Chrome and re-run. Is this normal? Looks like CSS changes also don't always reflect the code on each re-run unless I browse with an Incognito Chrome Browser. Could be a caching issue.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/1015 and Ctrl+F5 for refresh